# PyQt 3.3.6: How to align text in a table?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a table in which I put numbers (as a string) in a column. For some reason, it appears that numbers with 2 or more periods (i.e. 5.5.5) will align on the left side of the cell, while numbers with fewer periods (i.e. 55.5) will align on the right side of the cell. Does anyone know how to change this?

Comment: It would be useful if you included minimal testcase code in your question, since I can only *guess* that somehow a "number" with multiple dots is a string but one with a single dot is actually a float, but I have no way of knowing for sure or knowing how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that the characters used for the thousands separator and the decimal mark may differ between locales, but surely no locale could sensibly interpret `5.5.5` as a number? Given that, it's hardly surprising that Qt wants to treat it as ordinary text.

But anyway, the docs for [QTableItem](http://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/qtableitem.html) suggest you can work around this by reimplementing the [alignment](http://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/qtableitem.html#alignment) function:

```
class TableItem(QTableItem):
    def alignment(self):
        if is_pseudo_number(self.text()):
            return Qt.AlignRight
        return QTableItem.alignment(self)
...

table.setItem(row, column, TableItem('5.5.5'))
```

The implementation of `is_pseudo_number()` is left as an exercise for the reader...

(PS: since you are using PyQt3, the above code is completely untested)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry if it was unclear -- numbers in my case can include periods, and I use a regular expression to check that the "number" is only digits and periods. I tried your code and it's telling me that 'argument 1 of QTableItem() has an invalid type'. I believe the only argument for that was '5.5.5', so I'm a bit confused about that.

Comment: I added two parameters, first the table and then "QTableItem.Never" (the edit type). Now I'm getting 'error return without exception set'

Comment: AH hah! I've got it! It works, except it's aligned a little bit more to the top (rather than in the vertical center of the cell). I'm also getting a bunch of "buffer size mismatch" errors, though it keeps running.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. My solution was slightly different.
When filling each item into your table, check it matches your '5.5.5' format and set the item to be right aligned.

```
cell = QTableWidgetItem(value)
tableWidget.setItem(row, col, cell)
# check the value matches your requirement, via regex or as below
check = value.replace('.', '')
if check.isdigit():
    tableWidget.item(row, col).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
```